Can I make a request with HttpClient and capture the IP address it used?
I am developing a service using dot-net-8 that will perform a small GET request from a URL supplied by the caller. As a part of preventing abuse, I'd like to check the IP address of the URL before making the call. As services like HTML validators and translators do exist, I suspect (hope) this is a solved problem.
If I may ask the same question in two slightly different ways...
(First Question.)
I could use Dns.GetHostEntry, inspect the IP addresses returned, and then go ahead and use HttpClient.GetAsync, but I'm a little worried about a disconnect between those two calls. Can I be reassured that both calls with return/use the same IP?
(Remember I'm imagining a hostile attacker. One who isn't beyond causing my DNS cache to be populated in advance with a "good" IP and timing a second request so that GetHostEntry still sees the good cached record, but the cache expires right at the instance HttpClient is invoked and its internal lookup makes a new DNS lookup and see a "bad" IP.)
(Second Question.)
As there's also the complication of GetHostEntry potentially returning many IP addresses and not knowing which one will be used, I'd ideally like to be able to interrupt the TLS/HTTP connection at the point its about to open the underlying connection to the remote web server and my code will make the decision to make the connection (or not) once the IP its going to use is known.
Can HttpClient help me capture its own DNS lookup result? Or am I doomed to have to write my own using TcpClient, SslStream and my own HTTP code.
(Just to fill in an avenue that didn't seem to work - I tried connecting to a URL with the IP address instead of the host name, but TLS failed because I'm relying on TLS-SNI, which needs the original name.)
I'm open to any alternative ideas you may have.

I think you're overthinking this...
Simply use TLS and ensure that the Certificate and it's chain are valid and that the names match.  Which should be being done by default anyways.

@Charles My motivation is to not be the source of a denial-of-service attack by making my service flood requests to a target. Even a TLS handshake that's abandoned could be a nuisance in bulk.

Then add rate limits and exponential backoff to your request pipline.

I plan to have fairly generous rate limits for requests coming in, I can take it. There's no problem with many requests coming in being reflected in many requests going out spread over the whole internet.
Its when there are many outgoing calls to one place I want to detect and block.
